# Is it possible to run a job on the main thread using WorkManager on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

We are using an SDK that requires calls to be made on the main thread. For a Worker that needs to run in the background once a day using WorkManager, I have set:

```
@HiltWorker
class MyWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    val mySdkRepo: MyRepository
): CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    mySdkRepo.callFunc()
    }
}
```

but an error is given below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Event bus [Bus "default"] accessed from non-main thread null
at com.squareup.otto.ThreadEnforcer$2.enforce(ThreadEnforcer.java:47)
at com.squareup.otto.Bus.register(Bus.java:188)
```

It seems that it is not possible to run the code on the Main thread. I have even tried using runBlocking. When the app is open, this code works fine though.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ContextCompat provides a method to get the main thread executor:

```
ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context).execute {
  // main Thread
}
```

Or use Handler:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {  
 // main Thread
}
```

Comment: Did not work- same error.

Comment: This worked actually, but the problem I had was not the worker thread. It was the dependency repo creation thread.